# How to implement custom validation styling for an entire model (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently developing custom validation codes in MVC3. I have a number of rules to each property, as well as make rules for the whole model itself, as sampled below:

**Validation Code:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public sealed class VerifyRoleIntegrityAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        RoleItem item = (RoleItem)value;
        if (item.Name == null && item.UserId != 0)
            return new ValidationResult("Error: Name is missing");

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
[VerifyRoleIntegrity]
public class RoleItem //imagine this as a single row of div, there's a list of them
{
    [ValidUser]
    public string Name { get; set; } //bound to a textbox using Html.TextBoxFor
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsUserType1 { get; set; }
    public bool IsUserType2 { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="ad-row">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
    <div class="ad-cell">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
    </div>
    <div class="ad-cell">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin)
    </div>
    <div class="ad-cell">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsUserType1)
    </div>
    <div class="ad-cell">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsUserType2)
    </div>
</div>
```

For ValidUser, whenever I encounter a validation error after posting, MVC conveniently gives the textbox a clean red highlight without me styling anything. This is my intended behavior.

For VerifyRoleIntegrity though, I want the entire erring row highlighted somehow, maybe change the background color of its enclosing div. Currently all I can implement is a Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model) where I can output the error message of my custom validation class. Rather that just a message, I want the validation styled.

I figured I need to delve somewhere in the built-in jquery and css files given to me by MVC, but I do not have enough javascript/css knowledge to do it properly, so I want to seek assistance to complete the circle. Most of what I found online stops at how to implement ValidationAttribute but beyond that I have not found much. Also, I realize that I could make a hack out of detecting the added validation message via javascript to do something with that div row, but that's a hack and not a proper implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the [`jquery Validation`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods) plugin to do the validation?

Comment: There are a number of plugins added into the solution, like jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js which might be relevant.

Comment: I see that you are using jQuery validation plugin. When some element validation fails. it does highlight that particular element with yellow to be default & also the error msg showsup in red. Isn't it working that way?

Comment: It does work, at least just for ValidUser. The element (the textbox) gets highlighted with red (not yellow) and that is as intended. For VerifyRoleIntegrity though (the whole model), there is no element that will be highlighted.